# SQL Select item with escape characters

Tags: php, mysql

My table has values with quotes and other unescaped characters, and when I

```
$sometitle = "Ra's al Ghul";
SELECT * from mytable WHERE title='{$sometitle}'
```

ofc I got an error.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: *"I got an error"* - Being what`, error near 's`? and which api is used to connect with?

Comment: you also posted pseudo code; what you have now is invalid/incomplete.

Comment: Use prepared statements ([PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) docs). You'll never have to worry about escaping quotes again.

Comment: smells like injection to *moi* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1 being a possible dupe I feel.

Comment: Yes, `prepare` is solution